# Connecting senesor to aws iot

Tags: amazon-web-services

We had tried to connect a sensor to aws iot. The sensor got connected to aws iot but we are not able to view the message on shadow. Our shadow is not getting updated. Please suggest some ways so that we can update our shadow.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please add more info about what or how you are trying to solve your problem. It will be easier to understand the actual problem.

Comment: Hii ! I am connecting sensor data to the aws iot cloud. During connection shadow has to get updated so that we can see the messages that are being sent to to the cloud using MOTT protocol. The issue is that shadow is not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

The below is a class I created to interact with AWS IoT shadows that has ways to read, update, and delete shadows. The main thing here is I used a [boto3 client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iot-data.html) to connect to AWS IoT and this allows me to push and pull JSON to store in the cloud (a thing's shadow).

```
import boto3
import logging
import json

# Initialize logger for CloudWatch logs
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


class IoTOps:
    """
    Params: iotClient boto3 client used to update thing's shadow and also send 
    messages to the thing
        topic STRING - the MQTT Topic to send a message to
        QoS - INT - Essentially the channel of a specific topic to communicate
        over
    """
    def __init__(self, iotConfig):
        self.iotClient = boto3.client('iot-data', region_name='us-east-1')
        self.topic = iotConfig['topic']
        self.QoS = iotConfig['QoS']
        self.thingName = iotConfig['thingName']

    def publish_mqtt_message(self, payload):
        """                                                                        
        Description: Send MQTT message to MQTT Topic                         

        Return: None                                                          
        """                                                                       
        # Publish a MQTT message to a topic for our thing to ingest               
        logger.info('publishing MQTT message to topic: {}'.format(self.topic))         
        self.iotClient.publish(                                                           
            topic=self.topic,                     
            qos=self.QoS,                                                               
            payload=json.dumps(payload)                                   
        )  
        return

    def update_shadow(self, payload):
        """
        Summary: Updates a things shadow for a specified thing
        Return The state information in a JSON format
        """
        updatedPayload = {'state': {'desired': payload}}
        response = self.iotClient.update_thing_shadow(
            thingName=self.thingName,
            payload=json.dumps(updatedPayload)
        )
        return response

    def get_shadow(self):
        """
        Summary: gets thing shadow for a specified thing
        Return: The state information in JSON format
        """
        response = self.iotClient.get_thing_shadow(
            thingName=self.thingName
        )
        response = json.loads(response['payload'].read().decode('utf-8'))['state']['desired']
        return response

    def delete_shadow(self):
        """
        Summary: deletes thing shadow for a specified thing
        Return: The state information in a JSON format
        """
        response = self.iotClient.delete_thing_shadow(
            thingName=self.thingName
        )
        return response
```

Comment: The above code is the communication between python and aws iot. I want for sensor esp8266 and aws iot

Comment: Hi @shashanksureshkumar, to answer this I think we need to know more about your environment. It looks like esp8266 is often used with arduino. I think this repository will likely be of use for you: https://github.com/heskew/aws-sdk-arduino as well as this blog: https://iotdesignpro.com/projects/getting-started-with-esp8266-and-amazon-aws-iot

Comment: What information do you want about the environment?

Comment: I would like to know what language you are using to communicate with AWS IoT?